# How to return different functions and their arguments in a container?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement something similar to Redux in C++. The idea is, for each event that happens, I have an action mapping to it. Each action is a pure function, it takes a state as input, it will return a new state, also with the new side effects. I have a dispatch function, when an event happens, it calls the action, get the new state and the side effects, it update the state, and realize the side effects.

In pseudo code, dispatch function might look like this:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void Store::dispatch(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    auto [newState, effect] = std::forward<F>(f)(_state, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    _state = newState;
    if (effect)
       effect(*this)
}
```

An action looks like this:

```
std::pair<State, Effect> fellOnFloor(State state)
{
    auto effect = [isDead = state.isDead](auto& ctx) {
        ctx.rollOver();
        if (isDead) {
            ctx.bury(feet(6));
        }
    };

    state.isBuried = true;
    return {state, effect};
}
```

Currently, for effects, I simply return a lambda block. But I hope it can be some data struct instead, so I can simply check the returned data to see if it has the correct side effect generated in unit tests.

```
std::pair<State, Effects> fellOnFloor(State state)
{
    auto effects = Effects();
    effects.insert(rollOver);
    if (state.isDead)
        effects.insert(bury, feet(6));

    state.isBuried = true;
    return {state, effects};
}

void testFellOnFloor()
{
    State state{.isDead = true};
    State expectedState{.isDead = true, .isBuried = true};
    auto expectedEffects = Effects{Effect(rollOver), Effect(bury, feet(6))};

    auto [newState, effects] = fellOnFloor(state);
    assert_equal(expectedState, newState);
    assert_equal(expectedEffects, effects);
}
```

To achieve that, I need an `Effects` container, it holds different kind of side effect functions and their arguments. This is really intuitive in JavaScript or Clojure, but it's extremely hard in C++.

First the functions have different signatures, so they are already different types. And different signature has different parameters. Is there a good data structure to hold them?

Comment: So, this is a good question, in my opinion, but also a difficult one to answer succinctly, generally, and well.  What you are wanting, in my opinion, is a "C++ command pattern implementation".  Even that is debatable.  But not a bad place to start.  Another thing you could look at would be `variadic arguments` and keep in mind the equivalent of `Object` in C++ is `void *`.  Although you could always make your own base type for all your arguments or argument containers, or both.  Any type-safety you can keep is great.  But I'd try the first suggestion first.

Comment: To edit myself, `void *` and `Object` are not *equivalent*.  But...for the purpose of "I'll let the callee decide what type of object this is", they are *somewhat* interchangeable.